# Find an Equation Given the Parameter: $x=t\cos(t),\ y=t\sin(t),\ t=π$

Tags: calculus

Find an equation of the tangent to the curve at the point corresponding to the given value of the parameter: $x=t\cos(t),\ y=t\sin(t),\ t=π$

Comment: My answer was $y=-\pi(x+\pi)$ but it was declared wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t}=\cos t-t\sin t, \frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}t}=\sin t+t\cos t$$
Thefore,
$$(x,y)=(-\pi,0), (x',y')=(-1,-\pi)$$
Equation of the line is
$$y=\pi(x+\pi)$$

Comment: I calculate the same value but the program I am using stated it was wrong.

Comment: You stated $-\pi(x+\pi)$ above. I'm not sure if you also tried $\pi(x+\pi)$.